# API OF Task In Activity?

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks

[image: what is api of Task ?]
i want to create  page same as show in image .

i need task field in my page so anyone help me to know what is task API name ?

```
"select id, Subject, Who.Name,IsTask,ActivityDate,Status, Priority,What.Name, Owner.Name from task."
```

It's not worked

Comment: can you share your current code and highlight where its failing and give us the error you are getting

Comment: in above query all the field worked except IsTask ? now i'll only fetching data from task .

Comment: select id, Subject, Who.Name,IsTask,ActivityDate,Status, Priority
                             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
No such column 'IsTask' on entity 'Task'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: i don't know API of task , i just want to know API name of task ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query custom fields on Activity?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45073/how-to-query-custom-fields-on-activity)

Comment: it's not custom field.

Comment: This blog might helpful... http://www.ericsantiago.com/eric_santiago/2012/04/query-tasks-notes-attachments-by-object-type-using-soql.html

Answer (score 1):

Activities list all Tasks and Events. So you need to query both `Task` and `Event` objects. The Task column does not represent a field on the object, it rather indicates whether the activity record is a task or not (it's an event).